# Dropdown list not animating .slideDown() in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a nav list with a nested  which I want to expand down (and up) when hovered on. The .slideUp() function works flawlessly, but the .slideDown() is not animating at all.

```js
$('.dropdownLink').hover(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#dropdown').slideDown(900, function() {
    $('#dropdown').css("visibility", "visible");
  });
}, function() {
  $('#dropdown').slideUp(900, function() {
    $('#dropdown').css("visibility", "hidden");
  });
});
```

```css
#dropdown {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding-top: 10px;
  visibility: hidden;
}

#dropdown li {
  margin-top: 13px;
}

#dropdown li a {
  font-size: 0.9em;
  padding: 3px 3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navigation">
  <ul>
    <li><a class="link" href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a class="link dropdownLink" href="#">Models <i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i></a>
      <ul id="dropdown">
        <li><a class="link" href="#">Model S</a></li>
        <li><a class="link" href="#">Model 3</a></li>
        <li><a class="link" href="#">Model X</a></li>
        <li><a class="link" href="#">Cybertruck</a></li>
        <li><a class="link" href="#">Roadster</a></li>
        <li><a class="link" href="#">Energy</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a class="link" href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a class="link" href="#">Order</a></li>
    <li><a class="link" href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to play with `visibility`. Just add `display: none` to your CSS, jQuery will take care of the rest.

Also, don't add the `hover` event listener to the link. As soon as you'll move your mouse towards the submenu, it will disappear because your cursor won't be hovering the link anymore. Instead, you can add it to the parent `<li>`.

And finally, as mentioned below by @Taplar, to avoid animation stacking when you move in and out fast, use `.stop()`:

```js
$('.dropdownContainer').hover(function(e) { // <---
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#dropdown').stop().slideDown(900); // <---
}, function() {
  $('#dropdown').stop().slideUp(900);   // <---
});
```

```css
#dropdown {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding-top: 10px;
  display: none; /* <------------------------- */
}

#dropdown li {
  margin-top: 13px;
}

#dropdown li a {
  font-size: 0.9em;
  padding: 3px 3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navigation">
  <ul>
    <li><a class="link" href="#">Home</a></li>
    <!--         vvvvvvvvv            -->
    <li class="dropdownContainer"><a class="link dropdownLink" href="#">Models <i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i></a>
      <ul id="dropdown">
        <li><a class="link" href="#">Model S</a></li>
        <li><a class="link" href="#">Model 3</a></li>
        <li><a class="link" href="#">Model X</a></li>
        <li><a class="link" href="#">Cybertruck</a></li>
        <li><a class="link" href="#">Roadster</a></li>
        <li><a class="link" href="#">Energy</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a class="link" href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a class="link" href="#">Order</a></li>
    <li><a class="link" href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Side note; not a part of the original issue, but if you mouse on/off/on/off the link real fast, the animations stack.  You can address that with the usage of https://api.jquery.com/stop or https://api.jquery.com/finish